# Angular: why doesn't my app component detect observable changes pushed by my error handler?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My idea is that I'll have a global error handler service that catches all uncaught errors and provides the error as an observable to any interested components. I want to subscribe to the observable from my app component, and if there's an error, show an error page.

```js
//error-service.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ErrorService implements ErrorHandler {
  error = new Subject<Error>();

  handleError(error: any): void {
    console.error('ERROR', error);
    this.error.next(error);
  }
}
```

This ErrorService is registered as the global error handler for the app module.

```js
//app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorService }],
  //...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The ErrorService is injected into the app component.

```js
//app.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  error = this.errorService.error;

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {}
}
```

The app component template displays the error page if there's an error, otherwise displays the router outlet.

```html
//app.component.html

<app-error-page *ngIf="error | async"></app-error-page>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!(error | async)"></router-outlet>
```

However, it's not working. The global error handler is indeed catching the uncaught errors, so it's registered properly and the `handleError()` method is running, however the app component isn't re-rendering its template.

If I push a new error to the `ErrorService.error` subject from another component, rather than from the global error handler (`ErrorService.handleError()`), then it does work -- the app component re-renders its template and shows the error page.

Comment: Try using a behaviorSubject or a replaySubject instead of a normal subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue with the code in question is that

```js
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorService }],
```

registers a new instance of `ErrorService` as the implementation of `ErrorHandler`, so when I injected `ErrorService` into the app component, I got a different instance to the instance registered for global error handling.

This problem didn't actually exist in my original code though -- I introduced that issue in simplifying the code in order to ask this question.

The line above should be changed to

```js
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useExisting: ErrorService }],
```

such that the `ErrorHandler` implementation uses the same `ErrorService` that is already registered as a service.

Even with this fix, it doesn't work -- the subcription to `Subject<Error>` in the app component receives new errors but the view doesn't re-render as Angular doesn't detect that something has changed. I therefore had to explicitly tell Angular about the changes using NgZone.run().

```js
//app.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  error?: Error;

  constructor(
    private errorService: ErrorService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.errorService.error.subscribe((error) => {
      this.error = error;
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different instances of `ErrorService` in your App.

- This line `providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorService }],` configures a provider in the AppModule, with *dependency name* **ErrorHandler** that uses the `ErrorService` class to create that dependency.
- And this other line in the service `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})`, is somewhat similar to adding another provider in the rootModule with this config `{ provide: ErrorService , useClass: ErrorService }`

So you end up with 2 providers in your rootModule that use the `ErrorService` class, each with a different **InjectionToken** or *dependency name*

```
providers: [
  { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorService },
  { provide: ErrorService , useClass: ErrorService }
],
```

- When the App initializes and look for a dependency with a name of **ErrorHandler**, it will pick the first provider of the list, create an instance of `ErrorService` and use it as the main ErrorHandler of the App.
- But when you inject **ErrorService** in the constructor of your `AppComponent`, you are requesting a dependency configured with that name. So the DI system in this case will pick the 2nd provider and inject a different instance of the `ErrorService`.

---

IMO for your case the easiest solution is to manually add a second provider in the AppModule that re-provides the existing `ErrorHandler` under the alias **ErrorService**.

```
providers: [
  { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorService },
  { provide: ErrorService, useExisting: ErrorHandler }, // <---
],
```

This way when some element asks for an **ErrorService** this provider will return the already created instance of the service for **ErrorHandler**.

I will also remove the `{ providedIn: 'root' }` in the service in this case, to better reflect the behaviour expected from the service.

Cheers